# Run Oracle forms 10g over web

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I designed Oracle database for my project. This project has multi Forms and Reports. I test it on my computer, its work fine. Now I am looking for run these forms and reports over WEB. Could you please explain all steps.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that *anyone* is going to explain all steps for you; at least, not here. Those *steps* are described in a fine manual named [Oracle® Application Server Forms Services Deployment Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25016_04/doc/dl/web/B14032_03/toc.htm) (that document is related to version 10g Release 2 (10.1.2) (document number B14032-03). I suggest you read it.

Note that it won't be an easy task. Installing an application server is not trivial at all, and you'll sweat a lot before you make it work. Consider hiring a consultant to do it (or find a hosting service). None of those will be free; on the contrary.

Also, if you want to do it yourself, see whether 10g IAS is still available for download. 10g database is out of support and you can't download it any more (not without a valid Support contract). Maybe you'll even have to upgrade to a higher version (which doesn't contain IAS, but WebLogic server).

However, as you want to put your application into production, you probably know that database nor Developer Suite is free for you any more - you should purchase a license. Contact Oracle Sales representative for more information.

Anyway, best of luck!